# I am trying to update a global variable using a function which is in an imported module. Both files are in the same folder

Tags: python

```
# zzz.py
def Put(mess):
    global Dict
    global Lot
    print(mess)
    Dict = {}
    Lot.append(Dict)

# www.py
from zzz import Put
Dict={}
Lot=[Dict]
Put('abcde')
print(Lot)
```

I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Lot' is not defined
```

If I place the Put(mess) function in the www.py file it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Declaring a variable as `global` only works within a single module.  If another module wants to access it, you must `import` it.  See this https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

Comment: As @JohnGordon said you will need to add `from zzz import Lot`

Comment: Do you need to use global variables? Why not use a class?

Answer (score -1):

Global variables are not able to do what you want (as mentioned in the comment of John Gordon), but you could use a class as a workaround, like this:

Define the class in a module and add the **init** function with your "global" variables.

```
class zzz_class():

    def __init__(self):
        self.Dict = {}
        self.Lot = []

    # zzz.py
    def Put(self, mess):
        print(mess)
        self.Lot.append(self.Dict)
```

Then import the class and use the variables and functions from it.

```
# www.py
from zzz import zzz_class

z = zzz_class()
z.Dict={}
z.Lot=[z.Dict]
z.Put('abcde')
print(z.Lot)
```

abcde
[{}, {}]